# How to access new dataframe on the fly (pandas piping)?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a question about pandas' piping.

For example, I want to transform a wide table into a long one.

Steps I take: (a) `.T` and (b) `.reset_index()` to get the desired shape, but I also need to (c) fill missing values (table has merged cells) and (d) set proper headers.

What I'm curious if I could do everything in one pipe, and specifically, *if I could reference a newly created table (after `.T` etc) that doesn't have a name within this pipe*.

Sample:

```py
data = {
    'Variables': {0: 'var1', 1: 'var2', 2: 'var3', 3: 'var4'},
    'State 1': {0: 2019.0,  1: np.nan, 2: np.nan, 3: np.nan},
    'Unnamed: 2': {0: 2020.0,  1: np.nan, 2: np.nan, 3: np.nan},
    'State 2': {0: 2019.0,  1: np.nan, 2: np.nan, 3: np.nan},
    'Unnamed: 4': {0: 2020.0,  1: np.nan, 2: np.nan, 3: np.nan}
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Working code:

```py
result = (
    df
    .T
    .reset_index()
    .replace("^Unnamed", np.nan, regex=True)
)

# I split it because I can't access `index` otherwise
result = (
    result
    .assign(index=result["index"].ffill())
    .rename(columns=result.iloc[0])
    .drop(result.index[0])
)
```

Attempt to get everything at once:

```py
result = (
    df
    .T
    .reset_index()
    .replace("^Unnamed", np.nan, regex=True)
    # this is where I need to reference a column 
    # from this now transformed table 
    # that doesn't have a name. referencing df gives errors
    .assign(df["index"].ffill())
    .rename(columns=df.iloc[0])
    .drop(df.index[0])
)
```

So this question is more about how to do everything at once rather than how to transform a table (it's just an illustration).

Comment: sample dataset would be helpful to understand better what you are trying to achieve

Comment: you need to use lambda function in `assign()` without sample data can't give full solution. `.assign(index=lambda dfa: dfa["index"].ffill())`

Comment: @sammywemmy added sample data. The coded gives me the desired output, I'm just curious if I could do it all at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to achieve your results with piping - just minor tweaks to your code :

```
(df
 .T
 .set_axis(df.iloc[:, 0], axis=1)
 .iloc[1:]
 .reset_index()
 .rename(columns={"index":"Variables"})
 .rename_axis(columns=None)
 .replace("^Unnamed", np.nan, regex=True)
 .ffill())

Variables   var1    var2    var3    var4
0   State 1 2019.0  NaN NaN NaN
1   State 1 2020.0  NaN NaN NaN
2   State 2 2019.0  NaN NaN NaN
3   State 2 2020.0  NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: Hope it solved your challenge. Of course, you will have to check for efficiency and speed